# Rails thinks a new route is an id and tries to use #show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database full of text_message records. I am trying to create a custom "list all text messages" page.

Here is my relevant part of my routes.rb file:

```
resources :text_messages
get '/text_messages/all_messages', to: 'text_messages#all_messages'
```

I have the standard RESTful controller methods, then my own all_messages method:

```
def all_messages
  @text_messages = TextMessage.order('send_time desc')
end
```

However, whenever I visit "localhost:port/text_messages/all_messages", I get an error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TextMessagesController#show
>
> Couldn't find TextMessage with 'id'=all_messages

So, Rails is getting something after 'text_messages/' and automatically assuming it is an id, even thought it is a string, and is completely ignoring my route. How do I get it to use me route and not try to use show()?

I am using Rails 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `collection` method:

> This will enable Rails to recognize paths such as
>   `/text_messages/all_messages` with GET, and route to the all_messages action
>   of `TextMessagesController`. ([source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-collection))

Change your routes like that:

```
resources :text_messages do
  get 'all_messages', on: :collection
end
```

Without collection, any route like `'text_messages/<a parameter>'` hits the "show" action.

Comment: Oof, I had skittered around that answer for a while. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It is just because you have defined

```
resources :text_messages
```

before

```
get '/text_messages/all_messages', to: 'text_messages#all_messages'
```

by default resources add one route

```
get '/text_messages/:id'
```

which goes to the show action. this id can be any word or anything. currently when you are trying to call your `all_messages` it consider `all_messages` as id and goes to your show action and generate the error.

You can resolve this in 2 ways :

**Move your custom route above the resources something like below:**

```
get '/text_messages/all_messages', to: 'text_messages#all_messages'
resources :text_messages
```

**Use collection with resource as**

```
resources :text_messages do
  get 'all_messages', on: :collection
end
```

**or**

```
resources :text_messages do
  collection do
    get 'all_messages'
  end
end
```

Comment: bro you saved me tons of headache hours