# Routes causing legacy issues rails 5, cannot destroy etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

This is a continuation of my previous question: [Put or patch for new update action Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363468/put-or-patch-for-new-update-action-rails)

The solution to this question worked, however, the solution is causing other issues within the legacy system, I'll show the main two issues but I'm not sure how to go about making the system work peacefully until I can go about refactoring the system.

With `post :update` in place the following actions break, destroying anything, importing records, if I uncomment `post :update` then importing works, edit does not.

None of the forms are setup to use REST, which I can't change currently as I'm trying to handle the routes for now and then move onto the system itself.

Here is the example of a routes

```rb
resources :stock_groups, except: %i[destroy] do
   member do
    get :copy

    post :copy
    post :update # temp PATCH, PUT routes
  end

 collection do
   get :list
   get :import_stock_groups
   get :download_stock_groups_template

   post :preview_import_stock_groups
   post :process_import_stock_groups
 end
end

# remap wrong implmentation of paths
get '/stock_groups/edit/:id', to: redirect('/stock_groups/%{id}/edit')
get '/stock_groups/copy/:id', to: redirect('/stock_groups/%{id}/copy')
get '/stock_groups/show/:id', to: redirect('/stock_groups/%{id}')
```

Here is what I get when I go to import records
[image]
it's targeting the wrong method in the controller.

As for destroying this fails either, I did try adding something like `post :destroy` but this didn't work.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't have enough information but the error that's happening is it thinks part of your route is an ID for the stock_groups show route. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955294/rails-thinks-a-new-route-is-an-id-and-tries-to-use-show-method

Comment: @JustinAuvil I'm already using a collection, so this should be working, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well let us discuss error it is telling your exactly what is happening here. You are trying to searching StockGroup.find(params[:id]) which should be integer. As find will search your record by id value.

```
StockGroup.find(params[:id]) # only integer allowed
```

But in your request you are sending `id = process_import_stock_groups` which is not possible as rails convention you will have id integer unless you change it in model level by changing rails conventions.
So to test run `rails c`

```
StockGroup.find('process_import_stock_groups') # should not work but just try to know your error
```

Now which column you save this value in `process_import_stock_groups` so you method whould be

```
StockGroup.where(name_of_column: 'process_import_stock_groups').first
```

what you get? I hope it solve your issue.

Comment: I'm not looking into changing any code at the moment, there is a lot of technical debt, I'm purely just handling the routes. So the solution I need is purely route based.

Comment: Well but I have not suggest any change! I am saying you are searching something does not exists so you have to look how are you searching records.

Comment: Ah sorry, this is what I get in the rails console `StockGroup Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `stock_groups`.* FROM `stock_groups` WHERE `stock_groups`.`id` = 0 LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find StockGroup with 'id'=process_import_stock_groups
from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.2.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:173:in `find'`

Comment: Yes the message is also saying you same! try `rails dbconsole` and on prompt run `select * from stock_groups limit 3;` and show result what it comes.